How to get CIDR and put in Label (C#)
Can someone tell me how to get the CIDR of my IP in the form of a Label in C#?
I've tried different methods, but they either don't work or give incorrect range values.
I'm new to this business, so please forgive me if it's a stupid question.
I tried parsing and getting information from this site: https://bgp.he.net/
But it's closing GET method and this site sometimes shows me IPv6 instead of IPv4.
I want to understand how to get CIDR of my IPv4 in Label. Or no chances to make it?
